# Removing certain curly brackets from a String

Tags: java, json

I will receive this value from a server as a String value

```
 String responserecivied = {"dummyuser":{"Number":1,"CUSID":1}}
```

Is it possible to remove the first and last curly brackets from the above string , so that it looks like

```
 "dummyuser":{"Number":1,"CUSID":1}
```

Comment: Why would you do that? This is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), you can parse it right away, with any JSON lib at hand.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library) for Java JSON libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible:

```
String s = yourString.substring(1, yourString.length() - 1);
```

However, please note that your string is actually a JSON, so you may want to parse it using a JSON reader.